# Unable to access XML file in spring

Tags: xml, spring, spring-framework-beans

I am using spring and in that unable to read Spring.xml file.
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
showing me this error:
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

[*xml path*emphasized text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GPvl.png)

Comment: This question needs to be cleaned up a little. I'm not sure what the image link is all about, but it's better to supply code and other text information as actual text in the body of the question. Also, get in the habit of formatting things like code as `code`. If you [edit] the question you can improve this question yourself. This will help you get more interest by people willing to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Maven to generate a new project. to answer your question refactor your project like below and it will be able find the xml on the classpath

`src/main/java` - all your classes

`src/main/resources` - all your configuration, properties, xml, etc